# Single table with data from multiple database tables

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq, razor

In my dotnet Core project I have have 3 database tables: Building, Checklist and answer.

For each building I want to create a table with information based on the checklist and answer table. I have tried to set it up like the code below shows, but it doesn't work.

My viewModel:

```
public class myViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Answers> myAnswers { get; set; }
    public List<Building> myBuildings { get; set; }
    public List<Check> myCheckpoints { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public IActionResult viewData()
    {
        var currentUser = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        var vm = new myViewModel();
        vm.myBuildings = (from mb in db.buildings where mb.OwnerId == currentUser select mb).ToList();
        vm.myAnswers = (from o in db.answers select o).ToList();
        vm.myCheckpoints = (from mc in db.checks select mc).ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

my view:

```
@model List<Server.myViewModel>

@foreach (var building in Model)
{
    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => building.myBuildings.buildingName)</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Avviksbeskrivelse</th>
                <th>Risiko</th>
                <th>Dato registrert</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.myCheckpoints.Description)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.myAnswers.Deviation)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.myAnswers.Risk)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

When using the @foreach, I get the following exeption message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Server.myViewModel', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Server.myViewModel]'.

I am also unable to go from item.myAnswer to item.myAnswer.Risk.

Does anyone know how I can fix theese problems, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass a **List** of **myViewModel** to view:

```
public IActionResult viewData()
{
    var currentUser = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var vm = new myViewModel();
    vm.myBuildings = (from mb in db.buildings where mb.OwnerId == currentUser select mb).ToList();
    vm.myAnswers = (from o in db.answers select o).ToList();
    vm.myCheckpoints = (from mc in db.checks select mc).ToList();
    var lstVm = new List<myViewModel>();
    lstVm.Add(vm);
    return View(lstVm);
}
```

Comment: Add explanation please, so that the he understand what he is doing wrong

Comment: thanks, I guess i forgot that one, however it didn't solve my problem. I updated the question to include the error message i get when using @foreach

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you know how i can access properties in list tables within my view model like this: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => building.myBuldings.buildingName`? I'm not allowed to select the properties in myBuilding

Comment: buildingName is a List so should select a element from this list for example buildingName[0] >>>  : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => building.myBuldings.buildingName[0])

Comment: I am unable to find the buildingName. Even though my Building model contains buildingName, I get an error saying "List<Building> does not contain a definition for buildingName..."